# Potential sync issues with Invoke?

Tags: c#, thread-safety, invoke

I am trying to read value from control in worker thread.

```
    public void worker()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            ewh.WaitOne();

            int index = -1;
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate()
            {
                index = this.comboBoxSource.SelectedIndex;
            });

            // using index here
```

As I understand Invoke is launched asynchronously. Am I right that there is no guarantee at the point where I use `index` it `Invoke` will finish its work? If so, how can I make Invoke as blocking operation?

Comment: `Invoke` **is** blocking. `BeginInvoke` (`InvokeAsync`) are async versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> As I understand Invoke is launched asynchronously.

No, `Invoke` is synchronous, in that it will block until the delegate has completed in the UI thread. It's unfortunate that this isn't clearly documented in [`Control.Invoke(Delegate)`](http://From%20the%20docs%20for). The other overload ([`Control.Invoke(Delegate, object[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb) states that it's the implementation of [`ISynchronizeInvoke.Invoke`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.isynchronizeinvoke.invoke) which is clearer:

> Unlike `BeginInvoke`, this method operates synchronously, that is, it waits until the process completes before returning. Exceptions raised during the call are propagated back to the caller.